Troubleshooting Deep Link Behavior for website
Problem
I've been working on setting up and troubleshooting deep link behavior for my domain fosh.me, trying to enable direct navigation to specific sections of my Android app. Despite closely following recommended practices and performing numerous checks, I'm facing persistent issues where the deep links aren't behaving as expected.
The Core Issue:
The primary challenge involves ensuring that deep links intended to direct users to specific parts of the app are failing intermittently or not being recognized by Android's App Links system. This issue has been perplexing, considering that I've taken several steps to configure and validate my setup.
Steps I've Taken:
Here’s a comprehensive look at what I’ve done so far:

Deep Link Configuration in Android Manifest:


Ensured that the intent filters are correctly set up in my AndroidManifest.xml file, specifying the https scheme, app.fosh.me host, and paths like /email-verification and /password-reset.

Enabled android:autoVerify="true" to allow Android to verify my app's association with the URLs.
      <data android:scheme="https"
        android:host="app.fosh.me"
        android:path="/email-verification" />
      <data android:scheme="https"
        android:host="app.fosh.me"
        android:path="/password-reset" />




Assetlinks.json Verification:


Confirmed that the assetlinks.json file is correctly placed and is accessible without redirects. This file contains the necessary JSON configuration associating my app with the domain.
I am using Strato and a Wordpress installation. I am not sure if that could cause issues.
Everything is using https via a basic ssl - certificate.


Testing and Validation:


Used adb shell pm get-app-links com.fosh.app to verify the app's association with the domain and ensure that the digital asset links file is recognized by the device:


com.fosh.app:
ID: eef7faa2-90d3-4e4d-b8bd-f766df871dc1
Signatures: [FA:C6:17:45:DC:09:03:78:6F:B9:ED:E6:2A:96:2B:39:9F:73:48:F0:BB:6F:89:9B:83:32:66:75:91:03:3B:9C]
Domain verification state:
app.fosh.me: verified


Conducted tests using deep links to see if they open the app as intended or if there are any unexpected behaviors.


Server and DNS Checks:
Verified there are no unintentional redirects for requests to fosh.me that might interfere with the App Links verification process.
Checked DNS configurations to ensure there's nothing that could potentially lead to the deep link verification failing.

Persistent Challenges:
Despite these steps, the deep links are not triggering the app to open to the specific content as intended. All links open in a web browser instead of the app, indicating a failure in the App Links system to recognize the app's entitlement to handle the URLs.
I have no idea what else to do.

I don't think they work properly with debug builds, but Google Play builds work fine (you can still test with debug build using adb to make sure the behaviour is correct and also deploy to internal test on Google Play to test pre-prod release builds).

I will try to upload a build to the internal test drive of Google. But I think it should also work with debug builds.

It also doesn't work with the uploaded version to the Play Store.
